# Navigation in center

Tags: html, navigation, center, blogger

I do not want the navigation menu to be left-aligned but centered with space over the entire width. How do I do that? I use "Blogger".[image: xxx]
Thank you for your answers!
Best regards,
Tini

Comment: Provide code you have tried.

Comment: Does anyone know with "Blogger" (blogspot)? Since I must enter somewhere the code. Do not know how and where ....

Comment: Add your blog url !

Comment: www.tinisschatzkiste.blogspot.com.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Theme** > **Customize** > **Advanced** > **Add CSS**

Add this css code :

```
#PageList1 ul {
    text-align: center;
}
#PageList1 ul li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -4px;
}
.tabs-inner .widget li a {
    border: 0;
}
```

Then Press **Apply to Blog**